# Acceso denegano Mysql

Tags: mysql, contenedores

Tengo un aplicación php en kubernetes con dos contenedores diferentes que se conectan a un servidor de base de datos, desde los dos contenedores utilizo los mismos credenciales para conectarme al servidor de base de datos, pero solo desde uno puedo crear bases de datos, desde el otro me dice que el usuario no permisos, siendo el mismo. Para acceder a las bases de datos creadas si tengo acceso desde los dos contenedores, para consultar, insertar, todas las acciones excepto crear base de datos
¿Alguien sabe cual es el problema?
Gracias

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Ya esta solucionado, el problema era que usuario tiene restringido el nombre de base de datos con un prefijo y estaba intentando crear otra que no cumplía con el prefijo